# Using the Google APIs with OAuth 2.0 in Android

Tags: android, oauth, google-api, google-buzz

I recently found a very interesting [service from Google](https://code.google.com/apis/console) which provides to access to Google APIs for various Google Services like Buzz, Places, Latitude etc. I could set up a project there and create API access for web applications (via OAuth2.0) and native applications. 
I wanted to use the native API for my Android app. It API gives me Client ID, Client Secret and redirect URL. How do I use these in my Android Application, say to access [Buzz](http://www.google.com/buzz)?
Any sample apps, snippets available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this page: [Google APIs Client Library for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/)

You can see a lot of samples here: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/?repo=samples