# how to use google login information to login into my application

Tags: android

I am developing one application in android.

In this I have to login into my application by using Google account details.

Is there any api for this as like facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google uses OpenID

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID

The specific information page for mobile apps

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps

Comment: @koti Perhaps this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080862/using-the-google-apis-with-oauth-2-0-in-android