# How to login in my application through google credentials in android

Tags: android, gmail, credentials

I want to access `Gmail` credentials for log in in my Android application. I searched for this on Google but i didn't get any solution. Please give some reference links.Is there any SDK for that?

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Check this link http://nilvec.com/implementing-smtp-or-imap-xoauth-authentication-in-java.html and your question is possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271370/login-using-gmail-credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this may this helps you

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html

There is an sample in your sdk/extra check it.

/extras/google-play-services/samples/auth

Answer (score 2):

All google services are uing OAuth 2.0 (Gmail, Drive, etc.)

Please take a look [Using the Google APIs with OAuth 2.0 in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080862/using-the-google-apis-with-oauth-2-0-in-android)